# Modifying Error message at Client side. Custom Validation ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, custom-validators

I am trying implement custom client side validation.It is a cross coupled validation. I have followed all steps and its working fine. But my requirement requires me to modify the ErrorMessage which is will be part of metadata(HTML 5 Data Attribute). The example is as follows 
IClientValidatable implementation:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ModelClientValidationRule rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ValidationType = "salaryandloanconstraint";
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("loanconstraintvalue", _loanEligibleMultiplicity);
        rule.ErrorMessage = "Salary Insufficient to sanction a loan amount of";
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { rule };
    }
```

The message which i have initilized to **rule.ErrorMessage** is incomplete. I want to append text which is taken from input field for **LoanAmount** property to the error message when the user enters.

In Summary is there any way which i can manipulate the error message(HTML5 DATA ATTRIBUTES) at the client side using JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935568/jquery-validation-show-validation-summary-during-eager-validation), may be this solve your issue:

```
$(".field-validation-error span", $("#form"))
        .clone()
        .appendTo("#error-summary")
        .wrap("<li>");
```